# Http requests don't return anything in Flutter, and no errors are thrown

Tags: android, http, flutter, dart

This is really confusing me, using the simple default http library. Http requests never return and don't throw any errors.

Heres the doctor log:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.19.0-2.0.pre.34, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.19.0-2.0.pre.34 at E:\FlutterSDK
    • Framework revision 610dc170d9 (3 days ago), 2020-05-14 00:37:02 +0800
    • Engine revision b59e3e9c39
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-8.0.dev 2bf3259005)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at E:\AndroidSDK
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = E:\AndroidSDK
    • Java binary at: E:\android-studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at E:\android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
```

And this is the code:

```
clockIn(String number, String name, String company, String coords) async {
  print(uri);

  // var response = await http.post(uri, body: {
  //   'Employee_Number': number,
  //   'Employee_Name': name,
  //   'Company_Name': company,
  //   'Coords_In': coords,
  //   'Type': 'IN'
  // });

  var response = await http.get("https://google.com");

  final statusCode = response.statusCode;
  print('Response Status code: $statusCode');
}
```

I've tried try-catch as well, but nothing returns. There aren't any errors anywhere as well. Really confusing me. I tried it on AVD as well as my own device.

Heres where its called:

```
onPressed: () {
                      if (!isActivated) return;
                      getEmployeeData().then((value) async {
                        Position pos = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(
                            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);

                        clockIn(value[0], value[1], value[2],
                            "${pos.latitude}, ${pos.longitude}");
                      });
                    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling clockIn?

Comment: Through a button press, adding the code to the post

Comment: I meant code wise (with a code snippet). Might be worth editing the question.

Comment: Have added it, and already tested that part, was working fine

Comment: The part of print(uri) works in your code? If it's not try to call clockIn all alone without any condition to check your function.

Comment: @Lunedor Yeah it works fine, it just seems to get stuck after the http request. No error or anything. The code after the request (in the method) is never executed

Comment: @pskink I get Instance of 'Future<Response>'

Comment: @pskink no packet loss, there isnt an issue with the internet connection, Ive tried several URLs and APIs

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of google, I tried that code with different urls and it get respond for example;

```
clockIn() async {
    print("uri");
    var myUrl = 'https://www.msn.com';
    var response = await http.get(myUrl);
    print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response body: ${response.body}');
  }
```

Comment: Nope, no url is giving a response

Comment: I tried it and it works for me so that makes me think that could be a problem related to internet connection. Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to the stable channel and now it seems to be working fine on my mobile device, but not on the emulator.